# I booked a non-refundable non-stop flight and airline dropped nonstop service. Any recourse?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, alaska-airlines

I booked 2 round-trip tickets on Virgin-America from DAL to LAS, non-stop a couple months ago for travel in Sept. 2017.  I just got an email from them a couple weeks ago announcing a flight change, with a connection through LAX! And the flight time goes from around 2 hours to 5 hours. It looks like they stopped non-stop flights effective this August 28, 2017.  I assume probably due to the merger with [Alaska Airlines](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-travel-briefcase-alaska-virgin-20170331-story.html)

I know technically I just purchased passage from DAL to LAS, no guarantee for non-stop, but has anyone had any success getting a refund under this situation?

Comment: Why don't you call and ask politely? Who knows they might just do it. If they refuse then it's time to look 'round for ideas.

Comment: Usually you can plead a scheduling problem caused by a change of this magnitude and get the ticket refunded.

Comment: This kind of significant change to schedule should always be offered on the basis of "Take it or get a full refund." Non-stop isn't really the issue, but the significant increase in journey time. The email should mention this.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I calculated the total extra time with the new schedule, and called Virgin, noting the extra travel time would be 12 hours, also noting the new arrival time in Las Vegas at 6:25 PM wouldn't allow us to see any shows that night, she would gladly refund the tickets. She put me on hold, and after a bit I got a "thanks for holding; answer a survey" and after survey, got disconnected.

I called back, & rep said sorry, > 24 hours after reservation. I told her the other rep said it would not be a problem. She got my tickets cancelled & credit card will be credited.

Answer (score 13):

United Airlines, after beating you up, will offer you a [refund](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/help/schedule-change.aspx) if the change is more than two hours, as it is here. Given Virgin’s much better customer service, I am sure they will do likewise, even though I could not find a policy on their site. They may have better rebooking options for you, too.

Comment: Be careful not to rebook onto a black-eye flight...

Comment: While they will give you a refund under these circumstances, they will also do their best to keep your money by telling you as little as possible about that option.

Comment: Yes, the second time I called back, the rep tried to give me credits for future flights just on Virgin America/Alaska Air!  Fortunately she could not make that work and credited my credit card.

Answer (score 2):

The airline company should offer you a full refund. At least this is what happened to me a couple of years ago with Delta.